# About location of strategy pattern in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, strategy-pattern

I am implementing strategy pattern in Rails where I have Models like User, Item, Category and need to recommend items for the users depending on various algorithms (strategies) that user selects in view.

I am having a Recommend class which has an interface of recommend(user_id, strategy) and returns array of item_id. The strategy in recommend will be decided at runtime depending on the option user selects in the view. I have placed the recommend interface in /lib directory and the strategies in /lib/strategy directory.

I want to make sure if I placed the files in proper directories or Should I need place the recommend class and all the strategies in models or any where else. I am really confused.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Rails all domain-specific code belongs in `/app`, whereas `/lib` is reserved for external dependencies and shared code.

You might find "service objects" useful, they belong in `/app/services`. They are not `ActiveRecord` classes and have no database, they generally work (perform services) with other models.

You'll find lots of info on how to construct services e.g. http://sporto.github.io/blog/2012/11/15/a-pattern-for-service-objects-in-rails/. There is also an excellent Railscast (subscribers only) http://railscasts.com/episodes/398-service-objects.